# Smooth scroll when setting CSS element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm dynamically setting some CSS attributes on an element in jQuery and it seems like the animation is quite choppy and detracts from the user experience:

[image]

This is the code where I set the CSS attributes via jQuery:

```
  updateValue = _.debounce(() => {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#tableBody").css("visibility", "hidden");

    if ($("#div1").offset() && scroll >= $("#div1").offset().top) {
      $("#idHeader tr th").css("top", scroll - $("#div1").offset().top - 10);
    } else {
      $("#idHeader tr th").css("top", 0);
    }

    $("#tableBody").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, 1);

  handleScroll = () => {
    this.updateValue();
  };
```

This is my HTML element:

```
  <div style={{ overflowX: "scroll" }}>
    <div id="div1" className="container">
      <table className="odds-table">
        <thead id="idHeader">
          <tr>
            <th style={{ padding: 10 }}></th>
            {this.renderSportsbooks(marketOdds)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">{this.renderOdds(marketOdds)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I get the element to scroll to be less choppy?

Comment: Have you considered using CSS fixed/sticky positioning to avoid JS completely?

Comment: @DBS CSS fixed/sticky doesn't work when the container is not vertically scrollable. Only the page is scrollable

Comment: Sticky will work normally when it's the page that scrolls, there's no requirement for it to be the direct parent that's scrollable. E.g. [this simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/b5arygku/)

Comment: @DBS it needs to be fixed at the top but also scroll horizontally when the rest of the table scrolls horizontally. I found that "position: fixed" does not scroll horizontally properly

Comment: That's why the example uses `position: sticky`, which scrolls horizontally as you described.

Comment: @DBS the example doesn't scroll horizontally for me? Does it scroll horizontally for you?

Comment: My original example doesn't scroll because it's 100% width, but if you were to include it in a larger container, it would scroll. [Another example](https://jsfiddle.net/1trkx74b/)

Comment: Try to use `Fixed Position` **OR** `Sticky Position`